# Flutter The parameter can't have a value of null

Tags: flutter, variables, null

my teammate has the issue that flutter reports to that my variable can't have the value null, however everything is working fine on my mac. We could not find any differences in the code. Does anyone know which issue may cause this

the issues are basically targeted towards the constructor and the variables

I am using a Macbook pro and the others whose are not working are windows laptops

```
class DateTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  DateTextField({@required this.dateComposition, @required this.dateCompositionHintText, this.onFieldSubmitted, this.onChanged, this.focusNode});

  //dateComposition can only have Day, Month, or Year as strings
  final String dateComposition;
  final String dateCompositionHintText;
  final Function onFieldSubmitted;
  //onchanged function has to be determined if you want to automatically set the focus to another text field, see application on age_screen with the datetextfields
  final Function onChanged;
  //set the widget with its focusnode
  final FocusNode focusNode;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          dateComposition,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 7),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
          width: dateComposition == "Year"? 73: 55,
          child: TextFormField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            //Keyboardtype for numbers
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            //only numbers can be typed in
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(dateComposition=="Year"? 4 : 2),
            ],
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            autofocus: true,
            cursorColor: kPrimaryMagentaColor,
            onFieldSubmitted: onFieldSubmitted,
            onChanged: onChanged,
            focusNode: focusNode,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: kTextIconColorDarkBlue),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              hintText: dateCompositionHintText,
              hintStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 18.0),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 10,
                right: 10,
                top: 10,
                bottom: 10,
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: kPrimaryMagentaColor,
                  width: 1.5,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code causing the problems so we can have a look a it

Comment: I ve added the code

Comment: if you send the complete project to them and they try to build it, does i twork? where was the project created, on your mac? are you using git and maybe the git ignore is ignoring something important

Comment: we are using git, when i try to export it as a zip file, they cannot open the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please check dart and flutter versions in your devices
2. Check the version of packages used in pubspec.yaml is same or did it changed when your teammate did pub upgrade or pub get.

Edit:
I got variable can't be null error in this line

```
  DateTextField({@required this.dateComposition, @required this.dateCompositionHintText, this.onFieldSubmitted, this.onChanged, this.focusNode});
```

I made below changes to remove the error

```
  DateTextField(
      {required this.dateComposition,
      required this.dateCompositionHintText,
      required this.onFieldSubmitted,
      required this.onChanged,
      required this.focusNode});
```

If your teammate is getting the error on the same line please try this.

Edit 2:

```
class DateTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  DateTextField(
      {required this.dateComposition,
      required this.dateCompositionHintText,
      this.onFieldSubmitted,
      this.onChanged,
      this.focusNode});

  //dateComposition can only have Day, Month, or Year as strings
  final String dateComposition;
  final String dateCompositionHintText;
  final Function ?onFieldSubmitted;
  //onchanged function has to be determined if you want to automatically set the focus to another text field, see application on age_screen with the datetextfields
  final Function ?onChanged;
  //set the widget with its focusnode
  final FocusNode focusNode;
}
```

Comment: hi, ive checked all the stuff, they are all identical how ever it still does not work

Comment: hey yeah, we have tried this, however the problem is, not every variable/function should be required

Comment: Edited the answer please check